# Mongodb/Node.js : Can't access the value of an object in a json file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

I am calling an object from Mongodb database with `collction.find()`, and I am assigning the result to a variable called `EX1`

This is the response, which is correct:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5a351a5f5bd22b09ac494fa1"
},
"OrigName": "feras",}
```

Now, if I want to show the `OrigName` in the browser and I try to access the value with `EX1.OrigName`, I get "value undefined". Why is that?

here is the full code :

```
var Nameh = req.body.Name.toLowerCase();
var Numberh = req.body.Number;
cell.find({OrigName : Nameh , CellNumber : Numberh }, function(err, cells){
if (err) {
    console.log("Error occured");
}
else{
    cello = cells;
    console.log(Cello.OrigName);
    if (cello.length > 0) {
        var Name1 = cello.NameofDonor + " " + cello.Name2ofDonor;
        var Name2 = cello.NameofPatient;
        var Type = cello.Type;
        var Age = cello.Age;
        var Problem = cello.Problem;
        res.render("result", {Name1 : Name1 , Name2: Name2 , Type: Type, Age : Age, Problem : Problem});
    }
    else{
        res.send("Nothing Found !");
    }
}
});
```

here is the schema:

```
var CellPattern = new mongoose.Schema({
CellNumber: Number,
OrigName: String,
NameofDonor: String,
Name2ofDonor: String,
Type: String,
NumberofDonor: Number,
NameofPatient: String,
Problem: String,
Age: Number,
});
```

Comment: tried EX1["OrigName"]

Comment: @zabusa JS syntax shouldn't really care whether it's dot or square bracket notation

Comment: @Feras Could you please provide the actual code that you're running? Nothing from your question as it stands looks wrong to me

Comment: @MattFletcher there you go, check the post

Comment: Thanks. Any reason for `cello = cells`?

Comment: @MattFletcher I was trying to understand how variables work when moving inside another function or if statement... but no nothing important about it...

Comment: Well, you're looking for `Cello` when it should be `cello`, lowercase. `Cello` is undefined (at least in the console.log)

Comment: I actually removed cello and used cells, still not working

Comment: if i console.log(cells) I get the Jason file... but the problem is only when accessing the values